# Object Oriented Python

Tags: python, oop, function

So in the interest of practicing Python and more specifically understanding object oriented programing I have written this simple script to better understand the concepts. However when I try to initiate a "monkeys" object what ends up happening is Python adds the name of my first monkey object indefinitely... Am I approaching OOP right? And if so, where am I going wrong, because I can't tell...
Thanks

```
#! usr/bin/python
monkeylist = []
class monkey:
    def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       self.banana = []
               monkeylist.append(self.name)
    def addbanana(self, kind):
       self.banana.append(kind)

class monkeys:
    def __init__(self, monkeylist):
        self.allmonkeys = monkeylist
        self.monkeydict = {}
        for name in self.allmonkeys:
            self.allmonkeys[name] = monkey(name)
    def addbanana(self, name, kind):
       self.monkeydict[name].addbanana(kind)
```

The exact input and output is this...

```
python -i objtest.py
>>> bob = monkey("bob")
>>> test = monkeys(monkeylist)
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "objtest.py", line 15, in __init__
self.allmonkeys[name] = monkey(name)
File "objtest.py", line 7, in __init__
monkeylist.append(self.name)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: I cannot spot an error. Can you please show the full code, including your output?

Comment: This seems to work for me ? I'm doing m=monkeys(monkeylist);print type(m) , which correctly returns "type 'instance'". As Achim says, can you post the rest of the code and show the output.

Comment: Two minor notes for the future: (1) Class names should be in `CamelCase` (i.e. `Monkey` and `Monkeys`) and variable/member/function/method names should be `lowercase_with_underscores` for the sake of convention. (2) Classes should derive from `object` (`class Monkey(object)`) in Python 2.x, as "old-style classes" are just cruft and headaches.

Comment: you seem to have added a `monkeylist.append(self.name)` in your init. Its indented wrong. Only indent for block level. Also its probably not the best idea if you are iterating throough it in the `Monkeys` class to alter it in the `Monkey` class IMHO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you initialise a `Monkeys` with a list of names, instead of

```
self.allmonkeys[name] = monkey(name)
```

I think you want

```
self.monkeydict[name] = monkey(name)
```

---

FYI the Python naming convention is that classes be uppercased. Also I don't think `Monkeys` is a descriptive name; `Zoo` might be better. Note also that `monkeylist` is a confusing name for a list of names (i.e. not a list of `Monkey`s).

Comment: Thanks for the tips, your solution worked. I'm trying to wrap my head around these concepts and appreciate you help.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could do with a bit of a clean-up. The monkeys class is redundant, since it merely embodies the dict it contains. You could simply write this:

```
mm = dict((name, monkey(name)) for name in monkeylist)
mm['harold'].addbanana('green')
```

OOP is not an end in its own right. Use it when it simplifies things. In this case, using OOP for the monkeys collection created room for a bug to creep in (which is why I thought I'd post this as an answer rather than a comment).

Comment: `monkey(name)` not `monkey`. Also `{name: monkey(name) for name in monkeylist}` is a nice feature of Py2.7+.

Comment: @katrielalex: Thanks for the correction. Also, I prefer to stick with 2.6 syntax, at least for a little while longer.

Comment: Well if I were to see the contents of "monkeylist" i find that it has added the name thousands of times.... Also, wouldn't I need to have another class if I wanted to perform methods on multiple "monkeys"?

Comment: @Pete: I realised what went wrong and changed my answer (probably while you were writing the above comment). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, ok I understand. I was merely trying to create some trivial cases where  could use some OOP. But nevertheless, point taken.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want instead of:

```
for name in self.allmonkeys:
    self.allmonkeys[name] = monkey(name)
```

this

```
for name in self.allmonkeys:
    self.monkeydict[name] = monkey(name)
```

Or even:

```
self.monkeydict = dict((name, monkey(name)) for name in allmonkeys)
```